# Inconsistent browser-caching on Blazor WASM web app hosted on Azure in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, azure-web-app-service, blazor-webassembly, browser-cache

I have a Web App made in .NET 7 with Blazor WASM, and i am experiencing weird browser caching behavior with Firefox.

I made a new GET API endpoint, and noticed I was getting a 404 after publishing as an Azure Web App (hosted on Windows IIS).

I noticed in the dev tools network tab that the 404 was loading in 0 ms, which obviously indicates it was loaded from cache, and not the Azure server.

So i did a force refresh (Ctrl+F5), and the GET request now returned the expected text.

Now here comes the weird part: After refreshing again, it returns a 404 loading in 0 ms again, as if it kept the old cache. Everytime i Ctrl+F5 refresh, it loads the page from the server in about 40 ms. Everytime i refresh normally, it returns 404 in 0 ms, even if I have just done a force refresh seconds before.

This happens WITH the "Disable cache" checkbox checked in the dev tools network tab. This does not happen in Chrome, there behavior is as expected.

What could be causing this issue?